# abandon awaiting tasks, are they GarbageCollected?

Tags: c#

I have case:
`Screen1` opens `Dialog1`, then `Dialog1` opens `Dialog2`, then `Dialog2` either returns result to `Dialog1` or **closes** `Screen1`

Due to technical reasons I want to open each dialog like here (it's pseudo-code, shows idea):

```
// somewhere in screen1
var dialog1_result = await dialog1.ShowDialogAndAskUser();

// somewhere in dialog1
var dialog2_result = await dialog2.ShowDialogAndAskUser();
```

But sometimes `Dialog2` can close the whole `Screen1` and above awaits aren't needed any more.

```
// somewhere in dialog2
screen1.CloseScreenAndAllDialogs();
```

Can I leave above `awaits` on `dialog1_result`, `dialog2_result`?
Will GC clean it? (assuming that instances of `screen1`, `dialog1-2` are GC-ed)

Comment: What does `CloseScreenAndAllDialogs` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very hard to answer in the general case, because it comes down to *is the task still reachable from the thing that is going to say "here's your result"?* - and we can't answer that. Is `dialog1` still alive, for example? if `dialog1` is still reachable and alive, and the task is still incomplete, then `dialog1_result` will still be reachable and alive - because there is a reference chain in place to allow the result to be set *at some future time*. The converse is not true, however; the task should not keep the dialog alive (unless someone has used async-state in some unusual way).

Comment: The task in general is going to be kept in scope by the call back surely...

Comment: @Aron which directionality? if you mean "the thing *setting* the task result", then: that's what I said; if you mean "the thing *consuming* the task result" - then no; other way around - the task has a callback to the consumer - the consumer does not maintain a reference to the task (after it has subscribed)

Comment: The thing that is consuming the task is the continuation onto `dialog2.ShowDialogAndAskUser()`, which would not be cancelled, and will likely die due to `dialog2` being in an inconsistent state (but not collected). Collection is not the only state management.

Comment: @Aron yes, but the continuation keeps the *thing being continued* alive, not the other way around; ultimately, you end up with a reference chain back to the incomplete thing

Answer (score 2):

these tasks are not really abandoned because they are awaited. The question in your case should actually be "*What will happen with an uncompleted asynchronous operation?*".
And the answer is that this code will never be GCed unless the asynchronous method is finished completely (with or without exception). There's not enough info for us to say for sure. Everything depends on what CloseScreenAndAllDialogs does. If ShowDialogAndAskUser async method is never completed explicitly by someone then it will live and wait forever - compiler just cannot finish it for you.